# Hiveserver2 started but 10000 port not coming up

Tags: hive, beeline, hiveserver2

I am able to start hiveserver2 service on Centos8.5 and attached below logs when starting hiveserver2.

[hiveserver2 logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B88mH.png)

Also hive metastore service is up and running. Logs are attached below.

[hive metastore logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLvjq.png)

I am able to access hive shell by executing command $hive.

[hive shell able to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlCm9.png)

Only the issue is that I am not able to connect hiveserver2 ip and port via beeline hive jdbc string.

[hiveserver2 beeline jdbc issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SovL3.png)

netstat -tnlpa | grep  10000

[10000 port not listening on hiveserver2 server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FS4Ot.png)

Please suggest your recommendation to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.
Faizan.

I believe the hiveserver2 port 10000 is not up therefore we are not able to connect with jdbc string with ip and port and getting connection refused error.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Copy the original text to your question, and format accordingly. Probably best when formatted as code.